# Powershell script not reading the variable

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine

I have tried displaying the variable in my script and for some reason the value is not being recognized. I see the data being printed with trace but it appears the value does not get set in sending the email. I can run the last line and set the variable manually and it works the email is sent. Its appears as the " if ($freespace -lt 30)" does not work. I can see freespace is less than 30 in the data. Any ideas? Code below

```
Connect-VIServer srv-acme
Set-PSDebug -Trace 0
ForEach ($VM in ( Get-VM |Get-View)){
($info = $VM.Guest.Disk |Select @{N=“Name“;E={$VM.Name}},DiskPath,
@{N=“Capacity(GB)“;E={[math]::Round($_.Capacity/ 1GB)}}, @{N=“Free
Space(GB)“;E={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / 1GB)}}, @{N=“Free Space %“;E=
{[math]::Round(((100 * ($_.FreeSpace))/ ($_.Capacity)),0)}})|Format-Table}
foreach ($path in $info){$freespace = $path.”Free Space %”
$name = $path.Name
$diskpath = $path.DiskPath
if ($freespace -lt 30){Send-MailMessage -to user@acme.com -From
user@acme.com -SmtpServer email.acme.com -Subject “Free Space on $name on
$diskpath is lower than $freespace %”} }
```

Comment: Add an `else` block and write `$freespace` to console to see what it contains when not matching the `-lt 30` comparison. Might be simple typo or, say, object instead of integer.

Comment: I added  this code and  it did not trigger a value:                                                                            if ($freespace -lt 30){Send-MailMessage -to user@acme.com -From user@acme.com -SmtpServer email.acme.com -Subject “Free Space on $name on $diskpath is lower than $freespace %”}
else {Write-Host "value" $freespace}}

Comment: Use breakpoints to determine what is running and what isn't. Is Get-VM returning anything to loop through? Is there anything in $info to loop through? Just put in `write-host "Running for $($VM.Name)"` and such in a few key places so you know where your code is going.

Comment: Yes Get-VM is returning data.  For some reason the function to verify the variable amount does not show correct

Comment: I figured this out. The script did not even process the bottom of the script. When i add the variable BAGEL requested it was ignored. So i move the ending brackets and the scriot worked